# How to make  xxx.one.com point to yyy.two.com

Tags: hosting, dns, subdomain

I'm currently in need to have xxx.one.com point to yyy.two.com.
That means that when someone will enter xxx.one.com they'll actually see the content of yyy.two.com (URL in the browser won't change and will remain yyy.two.com).

The domains are hosted on separate hosting company. yyy.two.com is on a cPanel and xxx.one.com is on an unknown hosting plan, though I can get its details.

yyy.two.com have the same IP of www.two.com and this cannot be changed (as the hosting company told me).

Any ideas on how do I tackle this issue?

Comment: This is a ServerFault question, not a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the DNS issue, because you cannot change the DNS resource records by yourself.

HTTP/1.1 requires all requests to send Host: header, and modern HTTP servers will understand the header and choose the right object regarding the content of the Host: header.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23 for the details.

Comment: It is a DNS issue (at least partially). And yes I can change the records. I'll ask the question at ServerFault. Thanks for your help.